# How to temporarily remap colors on laptop display

Tags: windows, laptop, display, colors

My laptop is infected with the famous green-pink screen problem. I am looking for a way to temporarily remap colors on the screen so that I could use it in the meantime before sending it off to get it fixed.

I didn't find any option in Windows to fix this issue. I found a program called "f.lux" which somehow fixes this problem, but it is not made for this purpose and doesn't result in the best.

The screen looks like this:

[image]
[image]

How can I temporarily (or better yet, permanently) fix this in Windows?

Comment: Where can I ask my question then ?

Comment: Maybe here http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information since there isn't a way to rewrite this to be in scope for Super User

Comment: I edited the question, now it should be fine to be unlocked

Comment: The bad connectors could be in the hinges. Try to wrap them strongly with very thin Teflon Tape (or something similar) and it might "fix" the problem temporarily.

Comment: IF someone can suggest a third party software, it also can be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what parts of the screen get colored pink, but I'm assuming they are those that are solid white.

To correct your colors in software, Windows has a built-in tool called [Display Color Calibration](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/calibrate-your-display). You can search `calibrate display` or you can go to `Color Management > Advanced > Calibrate display`. Adjust gamma (and/or brightness, if needed) very slightly so that the magenta and green colors of death disappear.

If this does not work, you can always attach your desktop's monitor to the laptop and work with that.

Comment: the control panel for the GPU might also offer these tweaks.

Comment: I tried those settings. it is impossib to adjust to contrast anc brightness in a  suitable way with windows options. they seems very limited. I need to set low and high limits for each RGB channels. In windows, there is only high limit for each channel

Comment: @cloneman My ATI driver doesnt work in windows 10 any more. in windows 7 it has some options but still limited

Comment: @WOEITG Did you try tweaking gamma? It's exactly what f.lux does that fixed your problem temporarily. Also,  lowering the high limit is exactly what you need.

Comment: You are right about settings. the only problem is that there are many possible combination between gamma and RGB channels and it is very hard to find the best combination!

Comment: One of the main problem is that I cannot save the wondows setting. If I connect the laptop with another screen, all the settings have to be reseted.

Comment: @WOEITG Color options are monitor specific. You need to drag over the tuner window to the faulty laptop monitor (do not clone desktop) in order for the color settings to apply to the laptop monitor permanently. Again, do not attach a monitor when you are doing the tuning. The changes made will apply in real time when you are doing the wizard.

Comment: @WOEITG:  White is produced by combining red, green, and blue.  If the green and blue are weak, white will have a red tint and look pinkish.  Adjust it by boosting green and blue if you can.  If they are already at their max, reduce the red.  It will make the screen a darker, but you can improve on the color.  If the white has a purple tint, it is just the green that's weak.

Comment: it is possible that the problem is a corrupt ICC profile. Did you choosing monitor rgb or something else? EDIT: Actually never mind, the task bar looks fine, so this is probably a software/driver issue

Answer (score 5):

This is most probably a hardware problem and cannot really be fixed by software.
If the hardware has decided to display white as pink, then for the software
that color is still white.
The only real fix in case of a hardware problem,
until the laptop is repaired, is to use an external monitor
(might not work in all cases).

Here are some tests that you can do :

1. Test using a Linux Live CD

Booting with a Linux Live CD will tell in a decisive manner if the problem is
hardware or software. If the problem arrives on both Windows and Linux,
then the problem is absolutely hardware, and the next two tests will help to pinpoint
the problem.
If it does not, then let us know and we will suggest ways to repair Windows
(or the video card driver).

2. Test with external monitor

If both the internal screen and external monitor show strange or incorrect colors or any other image distortion, this is a graphics card failure.

If only the internal screen shows bad video but external image appears to be normal, the problem is somewhere inside the laptop display. This could be bad connection, bad LCD cable or bad LCD screen.

3. Test the LCD

If the last test has shown that the problem is with the laptop display,
take the top corner on one side and the bottom corner on the other and flex the LCD *just a bit*. If this further distorts or fixes the display, then your LCD is bad.
If it does not, then the problem relates to the video cable.

If you feel comfortable with opening the laptop and replacing parts,
you will find repair instructions in this article :
[Laptop repair - Screen shows strange colors](http://www.laptoprepair101.com/laptop-screen-shows-strange-wrong-colors/).

Otherwise, get professional help.